# Will geosrver run on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: geoserver, windows

I'm trying to allocate a box to install geoServer for my company's intranet site. We have a box with Windows 2012 R2 installed but I can't find any specific documentation if geoServer will run on this OS. Can anyone help me answer this?

Comment: As GeoServer is written in Java it should be no problem. The Java virtual machine is meant to be plattform independent. Also the Windows Server is in most cases usable like a normal OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; Yes

**Long Answer**

Yes, of course. You can use the usual [windows installer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/win_installer.html) and install GeoServer as a service. Make sure to read about [production settings](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/index.html#production).

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to make sure and there was nothing specifying the 2012 R2 os, although I suppose it's just standards windows os.